# Declaring function where the parameter is a class, returning an instance of that class?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write the TypeScript definition for a library I use. It has a Plugin system that I have no control of other than plugins must extend `Plugin`.  The `PluginManager` has a function

```
add(plugin: any, ...parameters: any[]): any;
```

Where parameter plugin is a Class (Apple.Tree) and returns an instanceof Apple.Tree. Apple.Tree extends Plugin.

Is there any way to make this a generic function and keep the type?

I tried this:

```
add<T extends Plugin>(plugin: T, ...parameters: any[]): T;
```

When I try to call it this function though, it says. `Argument of type "typeof Apple.Tree" is not assignable to parameter of type "Plugin"`

It says a property is missing in the Apple.Tree. However, since Apple.Tree extends Plugin, it is complaining over something which is there. I have a feeling it might have to do with this generic function.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that Plugin has a constructor `(game: any, parent?: any)`. That may be what the missing reference is.  However, that adds an additional layer of complexity to my question. Maybe not though, because `PluginManager` has its own `game` instance. And the `parent` is the `PluginManager`. So this function should not care about providing access to these parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just worked on a similar problem last night. Here's an example that you can apply to your situation:

```
class Tree extends Plugin {

}

interface ConstructorOf<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T; // allow for constructors with any amount of parameters
}

function add<T extends Plugin>(plugin: ConstructorOf<T>, ...parameters: any[]) {
    // create a new instance of plugin and pass in the parameters
    return new plugin(...parameters);
}

var tree = add(Tree); // tree is typed as Tree and not typeof Tree
```

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/204#issuecomment-122418608)

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks David, this works perfectly with all my tests. I used to avoid the plugins def like a nuclear zone!

Answer (score 4):

You can specify that the parameter `plugin` is a class constructor with this type constraint:

```
class PlugIn {
}

class TestPlugIn extends PlugIn {
}

class PluginManager {
  add<T extends PlugIn>(plugin: {new(): T; }, ...parameters: any[]): T {
      return new plugin();
  }
}

var manager = new PluginManager();
var plugin = manager.add(TestPlugIn);
```

The only thing I didn't do here was to apply the passed in `parameters` to the constructor.

---

The `{new(): T; }` syntax is documented here: [TypeScript Handbook: Generics](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) if you scroll down to the section titled "*Using Class Types in Generics*"

Comment: Thank you for your help Spike! One of those SO moments where it's a mashup and you're fine combing the candidates answers like the judge you do not deserve to be!